# Multiple uses for NFC

Tags: applications, nfc

I have my bank card linked to my NFC and since this day it is also possible to have my public transit card assigned to my NFC-chip. The thing I want to know is, is it possible to have multiple functions for your NFC-chip, like in my situation.

If needed, my bank is the ING-bank and my public transit card is from Translink.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to do but still here a suggestion:

With the App [Trigger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher) you can run two actions alternately. You can have various restrictions, maybe one of them is useful to decide which task you want to run.